# Multiple components slowing down other components

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my GameMap Component render() :

```
    var gm = this.props.game;
    const drawMap = () => {
        if(gm.status==3) {
            return(
                gm.grid.map((gridRow, row) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={row} className="flex-row gameMap-row">
                            {gridRow.map((tile, col) => {
                                return <GameMapBlock key={col} X={col} Y={row} tile={tile} />
                            })}
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <h2>Map Loading</h2>
            );
        }
    }

    return(
        drawMap()
    );
```

GameMapBlock render() :

return(
    `<h2>Block</h2>`
);

If I replace `<GameMapBlock />` in `<GameMap/ >` with the things in render() of `<GameMapBlock />`, everything works fine but when I use `<GameMapBlock />` changing in state takes more time. Can anyone suggest the cause?

Issue found :
Its due to connect(mapStateToProps(GameMapBlock)). Can anyone suggest how to solve it as I can't remove connect.

Comment: What are you doing in the `mapStateToProps` function? That's likely what's slowing things down.

Comment: I need to change my store dataset structure in an efficeint way

Comment: In general, it's recommended for components to either receive information from props, or from redux.  Not both.  Try to refactor to meet that standard and you'll probably expunge the problem.

Comment: Are any parent components connected to redux as well? You can try grabbing multiple items in your store from one cycle and then passing the relevant items down as props to the component.

Comment: I am only using redux. My mistake was that I was calling all grid data for every grid block.

Comment: @Andrew I did what you suggested and it works. Thanks.